# Hasura - Graphql Playground throws "GET query missing" 400 status code response

Tags: graphql-engine

I am trying to setup my graphql web UI console as below:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Hausra CLI - version=v1.3.3

Hasura GraphQL Engine: v1.3.1-beta1

So when I navigate to :3100 I get "GET query missing" 400 status code response. That is, when I visit port 3100 in browser I don't get a UI. Instead i get plain text "GET query missing"

Edit:
Ok so I learned that it's saying missing query because I did not add query parameter to url below

```
http://IP:3100/
```

If I add a parameter I get a proper response:

```
http://IP:3100/v1/graphq?query={hello}
```

and that nice I guess I can use this for development. But it would be nice to have the playground pictured above
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6tEN.png

Comment: Can you please include in your question, what you are trying to achive?

Comment: Hi Marek, thanks I have edited my question.

Comment: How are you running cardano-graphql? Docker? Or from source?

Comment: Hi Ben, I built it using nix-build so from source.

Comment: Additionally, are you running cardano-graphql locally, on a separate machine on LAN, or on the cloud?

Comment: Hi I am running multinode in the cloud. Node1: cardano-node, db-sync, node2:  cardano-node, cardano-graphql. Also edited my answer again please check for additional info.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I suspect there is an issue with networking/ports/firewall, but am not familiar enough with cloud to hazard a guess. Hope somebody can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the playground, you have to manually turn it out [using this guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/using-graphql-playground/).

Comment: Thanks Marek, this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest building GraphQL with docker-compose as it includes the appropriate dependencies including the playground. The instructions may change in the future and can always be found on the projects readme [0], however currently these are the commands.

Clone the latest release 4.0.0:

```
git clone \
  --single-branch \
  --branch 4.0.0 \
  --recurse-submodules \
  https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql.git \
  && cd cardano-graphql
```

Run with docker:

```
docker-compose up -d --build && docker-compose logs -f
```

And this will launch the playground at http://localhost:3100/graphql

[0] https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql